# Symfony2 collection form problems

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Im using symfony 2.3.2, and I'm trying to add subelements to collection by this way on my form type

```
<?php

namespace candgo\EventoBundle\Form\Ajax;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use candgo\EventoBundle\Entity\Entrada;
use candgo\EventoBundle\Form\EntradaOrderType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;


class EntradaAjaxType extends AbstractType
{

    protected $em,$id_evento;

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
      $builder->add('abc','collection');
      $builder->get('abc')->add('poc');
    }

    public function __construct($em,$id_evento)
    {
        $this->em=$em;
        $this->id_evento=$id_evento;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'show_legend' => false,
            ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'purchase_tickets2';
    }

}
```

I also tryied the code example provided by symfony doc

```
$builder->add('favorite_cities', 'collection', array(
    'type'   => 'choice',
    'options'  => array(
        'choices'  => array(
            'nashville' => 'Nashville',
            'paris'     => 'Paris',
            'berlin'    => 'Berlin',
            'london'    => 'London',
        ),
    ),
));
```

At both chases the rendered form is empty, Anybody knows will be the problem?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? how shall your form look?

Comment: Im trying to group, several custom form fields as "array"